# How can I setup OWA/Outlook on Linux with either Evolution or Thunderbird 3?

Tags: linux, email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, evolution

We recently upgraded to Microsoft Exchange 8.2.176.0 for our web mail. I've never had it setup for my desktop, I've always had to rely on a browser and access webmail.

I'm trying to set it up on my Thunderbird 3 on Debian but it doesn't seem intuitive.

I've also tried various ways in Evolution.

Here's the information I have currently:

```
Mailbox Server Name: Something.Global.domain.com
Outlook Web Access host address: https://us.domain.com/owa
Outlook Web Access host name: us.domain.com/owa
Exchange mailbox address: /o=Something/ou=Admin/cn=Recipients/cn=USERNAME
Client Access Server Name: Something2.Global.domain.com
Exchange Client Access server .NET framework version: 2.0.50727.4016
Server platform: 64-bit
Public logon: No
Authentication type associated with this Web Access session: Basic
```

Based on the information, can anyone recall what needs to be done in order to set it up?

Answer (score 5):

Since this question is on top when looking for "Install evolution with outlook linux", here's how it worked for me :

First make sure you delete everything "evolution" related

`sudo apt-get --purge remove evolution evolution-exchange evolution-plugins evolution-common evolution-webcal`.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315640/how-do-i-completely-remove-evolution) for further details.

Second, install the new recommended version of Evolution for outlook. **evolution-mapi is deprecated**.

Do `sudo apt-get install evolution-ews`, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776401/what-happened-to-evolution-mapi-in-16-04) for further details.

The new version of Evolution has everything it needs to work with Outlook right of the bat.

Open Evolution, create a new account, Server Type must be Exchange Web Services and fill up the forms.

Finally, there might be some keyring problem while fetching your OAB Url. Here's the different places you might want to look, I had to delete and reset everything related to Evolution :

- `~/.local/share/keyrings/*`
- Passwords and Keys, under Settings

**Update**

Thunderbird needs Exquilla to work with outlook. This plugin is a freenium and will ask to pay after 60 days. Evolution is a better long term option IMO.

**Update 2**

To debug evolution, run it by shell with `CAMEL_DEBUG=all evolution`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case any openSUSE user finds this question, this howto can help:

- [Use Evolution to connect to Office 365 on Linux](https://kamarada.github.io/en/2017/09/06/use-evolution-to-connect-to-office-365-on-linux/)

In short, use [GNOME Online Accounts](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineAccounts). To install the GOA framework, in case you don't have it already:

```
# zypper in gnome-online-accounts evolution-ews
```

Then, to add your OWA/Outlook/Exchange account, open the **Settings** app and click **Online Accounts**.

Comment: Just to note, as of 2022-06-01 this is the answer that worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Settings -> Online Accounts -> Exchange

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird will have to treat Exchange as an IMAP server, the instructions for which are readily available.

Evolution had a 'native' connector for Exchange 2003, but Exchange 2007 (that's what 'Exchange 8.2.176.0' means) broke it. There are packages that can do it, but it requires bits gleaned from the Samba4 project, which can break a Samba install on your local machine if you chose to use it.

Evolution can also use Exchange as an IMAP server.

Comment: Could you post a link to the Thunderbird instructions. I am wading through a forest of posts that say how these instructions are apparent, but I can't seem to find actual instructions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the evolution-mapi for the Outlook 2007 or newer server, so long as your organization has MAPI enabled.
you will have to install

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-mapi
```

Then you get the Exchange MAPI option in the new account dialog.

Comment: `evolution-mapi` is deprecated, use `evolution-ews`.

Answer (score 0):

So we have answers already for evolution-ews, and Mozilla Thunderbird using MS Exchange as a Imap server.  There is a third alternative: Beonex Owl and Exquilla Thunderbird extensions.  They are proprietary, but cheap and you can get a one month trial.